# How to achieve following result with Group By in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

Consider following table:

```
    +------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+--------+-------------+
    | client_id  | TradeDate | servicetype | SEGMENT | OrdChannel | orders | OrderAmount |
    +------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+--------+-------------+
    |      1     |  20140611 | Type_1      | CASH    | TT         |      1 |       39275 |
    |      2     |  20150119 | Type_1      | CASH    | DNT        |      2 |     11856.9 |
    |      3     |  20150922 | Type_1      | FNO     | OTHER      |      1 |      854750 |
    |      4     |  20151223 | Type_1      | CASH    | TT         |      5 |       71075 |
    |      5     |  20140529 | Type_1      | Offline | FNO        |      1 |           0 |
    |      6     |  20160310 | Type_2      | CASH    | WEB        |      2 |      8009.6 |
    |      7     |  20150318 | Type_1      | Offline | FNO        |      2 |      432900 |
    |      8     |  20150914 | Type_2      | CASH    | WEB        |      2 |       15612 |
    |      9     |  20160317 | Type_2      | FNO     | MINI       |      1 |        9000 |
    |      10    |  20140421 | Type_1      | CASH    | TT         |      8 |     17112.5 |
    +------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+--------+-------------+
```

I am trying to group this data by `client_id` and `TradeDate`. Thus final dataset would contain each row for every `<client-id, TradeDate>` pair.
I want to compute following features from this data:

1. For each type of SEGMENT in every  pair, I want to compute sum of orders and OrderAmount
2. Similarly, for each type of OrdChannel in every  pair, I want to compute sum of orders and OrderAmount
3. Finally, a count of each `servicetype` i.e. `Type_1` and `Type_2`.

Thus final dataset would contain columns similar to shown below:

```
    +------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
    | client_id  | TradeDate | SEGMENT_CASH_orders_sum | SEGMENT_CASH_OrderAmount_sum.... | OrdChannel_TT_orders_sum | OrdChannel_TT_OrderAmount_sum.... | servicetype_Type_1_count | servicetype_Type_2_count |
    +------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

So far, I have tried:

```
select clientsrno, TradeDate, SEGMENT, COUNT(orders) from orders group by clientsrno, TradeDate, SEGMENT;
```

but it's not giving separate columns for `SEGMENT_CASH-orders_sum`, etc.

Instead the output I am getting is:

```
    +------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
    | clientsrno | TradeDate | SEGMENT | COUNT(orders) |
    +------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
    |         44 |  20141209 | CASH    |            23 |
    |         44 |  20141211 | FNO     |            10 |
    +------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Why not provide a desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with a lot of  sum( CASE .... END)

this is a suggestionfor the firts column

```
 select client_di, TradeDate
   sum (case SEGMENT 
        when 'CASH' then orders ELSE 0 END) as SEGMENT_CASH_orders_sum, 
   sum (case SEGMENT 
        when 'CASH' then OrderAmount ELSE 0 END) as SEGMENT_CASH_ordersAmount_sum, 
   sum (case SEGMENT 
        when 'FNO' then orders ELSE 0 END) as SEGMENT_FNO_orders, 
   sum (case SEGMENT 
        when 'FNO' then OrderAmount ELSE 0 END) as SEGMENT_FNO_ordersAmount_sum
 from my_table 
 group by  client_id, TradeDate
```

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, I tried various versions of sum-case-when but getting a syntax error.

Comment: Seems like we can write with = as well. Actually we missed the comma (,) after TradeDate ! :D Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do for example:

```
SELECT clientsrno, TradeDate, SEGMENT, COUNT(orders), sumOrders.total FROM tabletest
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tabletest.tradeDate, SUM(orders) as total FROM tabletest
    GROUP BY clientsrno, TradeDate, SEGMENT
) sumOrders ON tableTest.tradeDate = sumOrders.tradeDate
GROUP BY clientsrno, TradeDate, SEGMENT
```

And repeat the process for every sum you need.